# Удаленное подключение к монитору

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование, монитор

Есть ноутбук, который физически невозможно подключить к монитору. Есть монитор, который подключен к компьютеру под управлением Windwos 10, имеющему выход в интернет. Есть ли инструменты, которые позволяют подключить монитор к ноутбуку?

Comment: Судя по тому ,что Вы хотите, потребуется платное ПО на подобие Splashtop Wired XDisplay, но для Windows.

Comment: Может ещё решения  Scalable Display Technologies помогут. Короче, нужен специфичный и платный продукт. либо самостоятельно написанный драйвер, обменивающийся данными по сети.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй по rdp. Рекомендую в паре с logmein hamachi, опять же безопасность. Ну или teamviewer, anydesk, и т.д.

Comment: мне нужно использовать подключенный к компьютеру монитор как второй для текущей системы, а не подключиться удаленно к рабочему столу компьютера

Comment: Берётся raspberry pi, и подключается. А на малинку, мы вешаем моник.